# Is it possible to change the insert point of an image in python xlxswriter?

Tags: python, excel

[image]

From the above image,  can we change the insert_image co-ordinates from (0,0) to (1,0) or (1,-1) in xlxswriter?

The issue I am facing here is that this image will be dynamic and will get bigger as the number of rows increases. The image will grow from top to bottom (header row in same position).

But my requirement is the opposite. The bottom row should have a fixed position and the image can grow from bottom to top.

code used:

```
worksheet1.insert_image(50,26, str(os.path.join(settings.BASE_DIR,'c_acwc_total_df.png')), {'x_scale': 0.7, 'y_scale': 0.7})
```

Comment: How are you inserting the image? The first argument to `insert_image` is the cell to put it in.

Comment: yes I am putting the cell position in the first argument. The problem here is that the image will be dynamic and the image will get bigger as the number of rows increases. So I want the image to grow from bottom to top not from top to bottom

Comment: Please *edit your question* and include your code and this explanation. It's probably simplest to use the `x_offset` and `y_offset` options (along with some calculation)...

Answer (score 0):

only the following is possible for insert_image:

{
'x_offset':    0,
'y_offset':    0,
'x_scale':     1,
'y_scale':     1,
'url':         None,
'tip':         None,
'image_data':  None,
'positioning': None,
}